# Orange pi zero под Ubuntu 16.04 переходит в спящий режим

Tags: linux, ubuntu, железо, sleep, orange-pi

После длительного простоя отваливается ssh и подключиться к плате не удаётся. Графические окружения не установлены. Может ли быть это спящий режим? И как его отключить? Или какие логи смотреть, чтобы понять что произошло?

Comment: начните с `/var/log/{messages,syslog}`